# How to distinguish between form data and jQuery variable when sent to php file from AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have sent form data and a seperate varialbe to a php file using ajax. My question is how to I distinguish between the variables from the form data and from the variable in the php file?

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on("change", ".analysis_progress_check", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (this.checked) {
        confirm("hello world");

        var form = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
        var this_analysis_number = $(this).closest("form").find("input[name='analysis_number']").val();
        var data = form + '&' + this_analysis_number;

        $(".test").val(this_analysis_number);

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "../server/insert_analyses.php?submit_analysis",
          data: data,
          success: function(message) {
            $('#success').html(message).fadeIn('fast').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');

          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

And the php example:

```
if (isset($_GET['submit_analysis'])) {
    $analysis_id = $_POST['analysis_id']; //from form
    $this_analysis_number = $_POST['this_analysis_number']; //from variable


    echo $this_analysis_number;
}
```

Comment: first look `var data = form + '&this_analysis_number=' + this_analysis_number;`

Comment: Perfect, did not know how to do that! Make an answer and I will accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this_analysis_number` needs a parameter

```
var data = form + '&this_analysis_number=' + this_analysis_number;
```